# Number of roots of $f(x,y)\equiv0\bmod p$?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, roots, finite-fields

Given a prime $p$ and degree $d$ is it possible to define polynomials $f(x,y)\in\mathbb Z[x,y]$ with total degree $d$ and number of roots at most $t$ where $t$ is any integer in $[0,B]$ for some upper bound $B$ that depends on $p$?

In particular can $t$ be $0$ or $1$?

Answer (score 2):

Sure for $d\geq 2$.  Just pick $f(x,y)=x^2-q$ where $q$ is a quadratic nonresidue mod $p$, for example, or if $p=2$ pick $f(x,y)=x^2+x+1$.

Note that an even more trivial example: $f(x,y)=1+pg(x,y)$ with $g(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ any degree $d$ polynomial, also give no zeros when reduced mod $p$.  This is essentially the only example for $d=1$.

Comment: Could you give a better non-trivial example that involves both variables non-trivially in some definable mathematical property?

Comment: @Turbo Something like $f(x,y)=g(x,y)^2-q$ would do, where $g$ involves both variable in whatever "nontrivial" sense.

Comment: The polynomial $x^2-qy^2$ works also, @Turbo. When $q$ is a quadratic non-residue, the only zero of $f$ is $x=y=0$. Not unlike $x^2+y^2$ over the reals.